# Limit with L'Hospital

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Taking a look at asome excercises in my book, I found this one. Specifically, it is in the chapter where L'Hospital rule is studied, but I haven't come up with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Put the expression together to get:

$\displaystyle \frac{x \,e^{2x}-e^{2x}+x+1}{x \,(e^{2x}-1)}$

Say $f(x)={x \,e^{2x}-e^{2x}+x+1}$ and $g(x)=x (e^{2x}-1)$.

You can check that $\dfrac{f(0)}{g(0)}=\dfrac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}=\dfrac{0}{0}$, but

$f''(0)=0$ and $g''(0)=4$ therefore your limit is $\dfrac{0}{4}=0$

I hope that helps.

Comment: I edited my first answer, because of a typo

Comment: The marvels that multiplying numerator and denominator by $e^x$ does... Thank you!

Comment: Actuslly, multiplying wasn't necessary: I was stuck because of a silly algebra mistake. And I even used WolframAlpha...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{xe^{2x}+x-e^{2x}+1}{xe^{2x}-x}$$

Now get to work with de l'Hopital (twice I think)

---

addendum

$f\left(x\right)=xe^{2x}+x-e^{2x}+1$

$f'\left(x\right)=2xe^{2x}+1-e^{2x}$

$f''\left(x\right)=4xe^{2x}$

$g\left(x\right)=xe^{2x}-x$

$g'\left(x\right)=e^{2x}+2xe^{2x}-1$

$g''\left(x\right)=4e^{2x}+4xe^{2x}$

Note that $f\left(0\right)=g\left(0\right)=0$, $f'\left(0\right)=g'\left(0\right)=0$
and $f''\left(0\right)=0\wedge g''\left(0\right)\ne0$.

That allows
the conclusion that the limit equals $\frac{f''\left(0\right)}{g''\left(0\right)}=0$

Comment: I don't know what kind of thing I did, but I tried exactly this and failed. Thank you!

Comment: Added something so that you can check. I hope I didn't make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Using $e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + ...$, and $e^{-x} = 1 - x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + ....$

We have: $\dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}{e^x - e^{-x}} - \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{x + o(x^3)}{1 + o(x^2)} \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$

Comment: (+1) good solution if they are allowed to use Maclaurin expansion